# How can I 'complete' everything in the prison?

Tags: wasteland-2

I have gone through the prison and completed the quests to get the radiation suits. I have also gone through and killed all the RSM (apart from the 'foremen' at the top farm).

The only things I haven't done are:

1. Release the pigs (I tried it but the whole farm goes hostile).
2. Release the women in cages, is there a quest related to them?
3. Is there anything else to do with the farm at the top with all the 'foremen'?
4. What are the options to get into the actual prison? I've heard about the robot, but never found a track for it.

Comment: If you release the women you'll get a furious rant on the radio from their owner, who'll be waiting to try to kill you if you try to leave the area.

Comment: Note that the NPC Shadur mentioned is tied to another question (given in the Citadel, to deliver a letter to a ranger's sister in RNC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The track for the robot can be found in Damonta (not any of the Octotron Continuous Tracks, you'll need the "#TRL-01553 - Tank Tread"). I'm not sure where it's found, I recall reading it's a random loot but that there's also a location where it's guaranteed to appear if you don't have it already: I think it was in the area where you defeat a certain character in Damonta (don't want to spoiler).

The farmer named Jobe will be important when you return to the prison. He is part of an alternative way into the prison (instead of repairing the robot).

So right now I know of two ways into the prison: the robot and Jobe. Neither can be done the first time you get to the prison.

Also, when releasing the pigs (spoiler):

> Make sure to disarm all the mines near the main entrance to the Prison area (I mean the area where the farm and actual prison are); if you don't the pigs won't make it to their owner. I did that when playing the beta. Now with the final version, I didn't release the pigs and when I came back later in the game they were dead so maybe you really have to release them on your first visit (their owner wasn't there any more on my second visit either).

I haven't found a way to release the pigs without the foremen getting hostile, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you get the pigs.

First, you need to disable the mines on the left when you enter the area. If you do not do this the pigs will path right into them and you will fail the quest.

Once you do that, you need someone with ranks in Brute Force. Angela Deth has more than enough when you get her, I believe, and go up to the farm. On the far right side of it there will be a gap between the farms fence and the rocks. At the bottom two rows of corn past that gap there will be a section of the fence you can use Brute Force on, and just inside and above will be another breakable part of the fence. Go through the second hole you broke and follow the path behind the farm all the way to the back of the pig pen. Break the fence there and the pigs will make a run for it. If you cleared the minefield, all three pigs will make it.

There are other sections of breakable fence when you're running around the back of the farm. I do not recommend breaking any of them, as the pigs might path through those broken sections, and right into the foremen.

When the pigs reach the travel marker on the map, go back to the farmer you got the quest from and turn it in.

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler:
Killed all the foremen, pigs can be saved without aggroing anyone (cause they are all dead), good XP from the fight aswell. Just be ready to lie to your Captain in the Rangers about it. Pff what dead foremen? I wasn't even there! Damonta is where you get the robot part to get passed the turrets. Alternative way into prison is; Use the night terror companion to take the heat from the turrets and kill the turrets with the RPGs you buy from the Demolition Shopkeeper in citadel and high combat initiative. It's a costy way but worked for me after some trial and error.